# Delete confirmation in asp.net gridview auto generate delete button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need to show a confirmation message while clicking the auto generate delete button in the gridview.

my code is here

```
 AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this event?');"></asp:GridView>

 protected void grdFraction_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        int catid = int.Parse(grdFraction.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
        var delQuery = "delete from nano_WasteFraction where FID='" + catid + "'";
        SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(GlobalSettings.DbDSN, CommandType.Text, delQuery);
        GridBind();
    }
```

I just add OnClientClick in gridviw.but it is not working.can any one help?

Comment: What do you mean by _not working_? You get any exception or error message? Could you please be more specific?

Comment: @SonerGönül I mean the confirmation is not showing

Comment: SQL Injection alert by the way...

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to use the below code on Delete Button markup?

```
OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?');"
```

It worked great for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
      <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
         function DisplayCancelMessage() {
             var value = confirm("Are You Sure, You Want to  delete this event?");
             if (value) {
                 return true;
             }
             else {
                 return false;
             }
         } 
     </script>


     And Add OnClientClick Property in to the delete button 

        OnClientClick="return DisplayCancelMessage();"
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this,

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
LinkButton l = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("LinkButton1"); 
l.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:return " +
"confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record " +
DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "CategoryID") + "')"); 
}
}
```